# The methods to generate UIDs

Tags: database, uuid, guid, uniqueidentifier, identifier

When I write server side apps I spent a lot of time trying to understand how my `UID` should looks like. Of course it is possible to use `UUID` every time but I do not think it is the correct way if you want to get better performance and memory management.

So in every app I try to find UID I really need for current situation. It can be `Instagram` version of `Snowflake ID` or hand made UID like `Google Analytics ID` which is in browser's cookie or `Google Pay ID` or `random string` etc...

When I try to search UID generation algorithms in the internet I see a lot of articles about UUIDs but it is really hard to find others.

**The questions are:**

- Is there a book or site where people can find some UIDs implementations?
- Which UID is better for small collection of data (< 500,000 items)
- Which UID is better for medium collection of data (< 5,000,000 items)
- Which UID is better for large collection of data (> 100,000,000 items)

p.s May be SO isn't the best place for this question. If so, please write Stack Exchange service name for this question and I will write it there.

p.s.s Thank you for spending time on this question, hope it will be useful for many people.

Comment: [Here is an implementation](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/e3019f631d1f2e21667ad05f903c52d904b9048c/src/backend/utils/adt/uuid.c#L413)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Hi. Thanks for response. I know how to generate UUID :)  I would like to know about other UIDs (but not UUID). I think there are a lot more UIDs like Slowfish ID, which are shorter and more useful in some situation)

Comment: There is no "best" solution because what is best for each situation will vary depending on what qualities are important.